# Sharing Preference Pane unavailable in Mac OSX 10.8.5?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, connection-sharing, internet-sharing

I am currently trying to share internet with a Windows lappy. Most of the sites out there says to find the Sharing pane in System Preferences, but I can't find. I assume it's supposed to be beside the Bluetooth pane, or at least on the same row. However, it's just not there.

I haven't seen anything that suggests it has been removed, so I assume it just went missing. Is there anyway to find it again?

Seriously confused. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it should be next to Bluetooth, but it might be hidden.

1. Open **System Preferences**.
2. Go to **View** → **Customize…**.
3. Tick the box next to **Sharing** and click **Done**.

   [image]

Alternatively, access the Sharing preference pane directly from the view menu, or by opening `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/SharingPref.prefPane`.

Comment: Strange. The Sharing pane doesn't show up when I do that. I'd like to investigate that path, but can't seem to find it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So in reality, the Mac isn't mine, it's my sister's. And it seems that the tech admin at her school might have deleted the preference pane for whatever agenda he had. So I guess we're stuck unless we decide to reinstall, which my sister seems unwilling.

Comment: @Jack If you have an OS X installer, you can use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com) to extract the preference pane only and just install that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. Also checked that folder, and it wasn't there as we suspected. Know how I might get hold of an installer disk/flash?